# Unable to produce tensor board in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to produce tensorboard in keras ..... But getting 'name not found error' even after giving correct path

Note : Have permission to write in that folder and tried without time format also

code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from time import time

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))

history= model_inc.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=9,batch_size=16,validation_data=(testX,testY),shuffle=True,verbose=1,callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please improve your question quality [following the rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the definition of the log_dir. Basically, TensorBoard is expecting a directory name not a file name.

You can make sure this works by using os library:

```
dir = "logs/{}".format(time())
if not os.path.isdir(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable